# CSS / LESS selecting elements NOT contained within a given ID

Tags: html, css, less

Say I have the following HTML structure:

```
<div id="outer">
   <div id="target">
   </div>
</div>
```

The outer div may or may not have the id "outer".

I want to apply styles to #target only when its *not* contained within a div having the id "outer":

```
<div id="something-else">
   <div id="target">
   </div>
</div>
```

With LESS, I tried the following:

```
:not(#outer) {
   #target {
     // styles
   }
}
```

This doesn't work apparently (I guess because the :not operator is not excluding its nested elements).

Is there any way to achieve this with CSS / LESS? Of course I know that I can refactor the html / logic so that I apply the styles without using :not, but I'm wondering if theres a way to achieve what I'm asking as is.

Comment: You know can't re-use ID's on a page...right?

Comment: I'm not...I was just illustrating the 2 different cases: one where its contained within "outer", and one where its not..

Comment: It's does not work because just `:not(outer)` matches *any* element that is not `#outer` including `html` and `body` (hence any `:not(#outer) #target` matches just any `#target` inside document). Depending on your needs use either `:not(#outer) > #target` (as already suggested below) or `div:not(#outer) #target`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
:not(#outer) > #target {
     // Styles
     background-color: red;
   }
}
```

Here's a little [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/48L7nb1w/) you can try.